# Pf. of weak lower semicontinuity for convex Lagrangians

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

This question is about the proof of Theorem 1 in Chapter 8 of Evans' PDE book (p. 468 in the 2nd edition). Let $u,u_k\in\mathrm{W}^{1,q}(U)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open, bounded, $L$ smooth, $1<q<\infty$ and 
$$G_\epsilon=E_\epsilon\cap F_\epsilon$$ where $E_\epsilon$ measurable s.t. $|U-E_\epsilon|\le \epsilon$ and
$$F_\epsilon=\left\{x\in U\,|\,|u(x)|+|Du(x)|\le\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right\}.$$
If $$u_k\rightarrow u\;\;\text{uniformly in}\;\;E_\epsilon$$
why does the limit
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{G_\epsilon} L(Du,u_k,x) dx = \int_{G_\epsilon}L(Du,u,x)dx, $$
hold? I suppose this is the reason why $F_\epsilon$ is defined as it is, but I don't see the exact connection.
I would appreciate if somebody could look it up and help me out :-).

Comment: What are $u_k$?

Comment: Ooops, forgot the most important part :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a consequence of mean value inequality, as $u_k(x)$ and $u(x)$ is uniformly bounded (says by $C$). Then 
\begin{align}
\small\left|\int_{G_\varepsilon}L(Du,u_k,x)dx-\int_{G_\varepsilon}L(Du,u,x)dx\right|&\leqslant 
\int_{G_\varepsilon}\left|\int_{u_k(x)}^{u(x)}\partial_2L(Du,t,x)dt\right|dx\\
&\leqslant |G_{\varepsilon}|\sup_{-R\leqslant t_1,t_2,t_3\leqslant R}|\partial_2L(t_1,t_2,t_3)|\cdot \sup_{x\in G_\varepsilon}|u_k(x)-u(x)|.
\end{align}
As $G_\varepsilon$ is bounded it has a finite measure and the supremum is finite (as $L$ is smooth hence $\partial_2L$ is continuous on the compact set $[-R,R]^3$).

Comment: Yes, I will add it readily.

Comment: Thanks for solving, should have thought of that myself :).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Its pretty clear, but where are we using $F_\epsilon$?